# Enunciate isn't generating Descriptions from xs:documentation on xs:elements

Tags: xsd, enunciate

We're using maven-enunciate-plugin version 1.26.2 and are encountering an issue during the generation of our documentation. We have added comments to our XSDs in the following manner:

```
<xs:complexType name="PagingParameters">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>information about PagingParameters</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0">
            <xs:element name="StartPos" type="xs:long" nillable="false">                    
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>information about StartPos</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="FollowOnBrowseToken" type="xs:string" nillable="false">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>information about token</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="NoOfRecords" type="xs:long" nillable="false">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>information about noOfRecords</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

The first  set gets parsed and outputs correctly on the enunciate page, however all of the comments for the individual elements therein are completely lost. Oddly enough this only happens with sequences of elements, but enumerations work just fine.

I've tried a few different means of formatting the documentation, including the use of CDATA blocks, but nothing seems to quite be working.

What am I missing? If needed I can include more of the XSD.

Answer (score 0):

Enunciate uses JavaDoc to parse its documentation. Can you confirm the JavaDoc is showing up in the generated Java classes?

Answer (score 0):

Javadoc do *NOT* show up in the generated-classes but then jaxb overwrites this with their own standard comment like this:

```
/**
 * Gets the value of the X property.
 * 
 * @return
 *     possible object is
 *     {@link String }
 *     
 */
public String getX() {
```

but still no javadoc is shown in enuciate